# How to find mongoDB bulk insert optimal bulk limit

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert

I have an enormous data to be inserted to mongoDB via springboot microservice. The microservice using bulkOperitions to perform bulk insert.

But I'm having trouble the find the optimal size of the data which will be inserted as bulk insert.

How can I find the optimal size to perform bulk insert.

I'm using mongoDB 4.4, and I tried with 50k as bulkLimit. With this limit service makes a lot of inserts nearly 500 times each contains 50k document.

Comment: provide your code and the error please

Comment: there is no error...

Im trying to figure out what is the optimal bulk size some collection